# Extend a LinearLayout instead of Activity in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Can I have a class which extend a LinearLayout, as the main class of the Android project? I'm new to android developing. Is it a must to extend the Activity class when we creating a new project?

If it is possible to have a class which extend the LinearLayout, can anyone tell me how to do it? For example how to add a textView, EditText something like that to the LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An activity is necessary, yes, when creating an android project.  Each activity itself hosts a layout with setContentView().  If is possible to extend a LinearLayout in a separate class, then set it as the main content view inside of a separate activity:

```
LinearLayout mainLin  = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
MyLinearLayout m = new MyLinearLayout();
```

You can then add the layout to your main layout:

```
setContentView(R.id.main);  // in onCreate()
mainLin.addView(m);
```

Answer (score 3):

LinearLayout and Activity are two very different concepts in Android development, and you should read up on both to see why the answer to your question is "no". In short, layouts (including LinearLayout) are UI constructs, which are the visual representation of what's happening in an Activity. But it's the Activity that is run, not the Layout.

- [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)
- [UI Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)